# Call Javascripts into rmarkdown yaml

Tags: javascript, html, r-markdown

I want to use [this](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/) to create an html that resembles the grayscale bootstrap site's lay-out using **Rmarkdown V2**.

I can load the css by using in my yaml:

```
output:
html_document:
css: css/grayscale.css
```

But how do I load the rest of the files into the rmarkdown yaml?

The folder examples from the [site](http://startbootstrap.com) above are all in a consistent format (css, js, fonts, img) but I cannot seem to get my rmarkdown to call either the js scripts or the images? Should this be done in the yaml?

Help please?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks, I had a look. I cannot see from there how to use the YAML to include the js scripts and the fonts and images to create a similar output than the link I suggested. Also, I use the latest version of Rmarkdown and use render. It mentions in your link: "Very current versions of RStudio use the render function when you press the "Knit" button. In order to output using knitrBootstrap use the YAML front-matter in your document." So your suggestion might not be what I am looking for? Unless I am missing something obvious about the rendering of html documents with rmd v2?

Comment: On a more general level, it would be nice to have the option to just add .js files to the header.

output:
html_document:
js: https://... .../awesome.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bookdown::html_document2` has an option `includes` here you can set e.g. `in_header` to an html file that contains what you need. At least for JavaScript its working for me.

```yaml
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    includes:
      in_header: "javascript.html"
```

https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html#yaml-options