# delete some ""powered by datacamp"" when using "tutorial" package

Tags: r

I am trying to make some R tutorial presentation using "tutorial" package. There is a link "powered by datacamp" after each code window. I think it is far too much. Is there any way to remove some of "powered by datacamp"? and make it show at the beginning or end of the tutorial?

For example, when you create a R markdown file with `tutorial::go_interactive()`, it gives "powered by datacamp" after each code window:

````
---
title_meta: 'R tutorial'
title: Vectors
description: ''
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
tutorial::go_interactive()
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
````

```
# no pec
```

Comment: As per here: https://github.com/datacamp/tutorial/issues/19 use the following javascript code: `$(".powered-by-datacamp" ).remove();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not have a lot of experience in javascript, is it possible to implement it using R and R studio?

Comment: See some ways here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130094/how-can-i-use-javascript-in-code-chunks-of-rmarkdown

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still can not make it work. I attached the RMarkdown code in the question. Could you take a try to remove the ""powered by datacamp""? Many thanks