# How to use JavaScript in code chunks of RMarkdown?

Tags: javascript, r-markdown

Using R Markdown for creating a web site that is based on bootstrap and want to include (ideally before the tag `</body>`

```
  <script src="load.js"></script>
  <canvas class="background" ></canvas>
  <script src="dist/particles.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried some of the syntaxes given here: [How can I use JavaScript in code chunks of RMarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130094/how-can-i-use-javascript-in-code-chunks-of-rmarkdown)

when knitting the HTML doc, it shows the code above on the page itself, like a code box, but does not call any js function. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: Include the js code above as is right after any text. No HTMLtools or knitr need.