# Is it possible to make a huxtable html output hoverable?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, kable, huxtable

Specifically, this works for tables produced with `kableExtra` which creates a very appealing effect. I was wondering if anyone has an idea how this may be doable with `huxtable`.

Here's an example Rmd to get a glimpse at what I mean. I'd like the huxtable to allow the hover effect that is visible in the kable.

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r lib}
library(magrittr)
```

```{r kable}
iris %>%
  head() %>%
  kableExtra::kbl(caption = "a caption") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "hover")
```

```{r huxtable}
iris %>%
  head() %>%
  huxtable::hux() %>%
  huxtable::set_caption("a caption")
```
````

Related to: [Is it possible to fix the head for a long huxtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75820617/is-it-possible-to-fix-the-head-for-a-long-huxtable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the underlying generated HTML for `kableExtra` table, you would see, for `bootstrap_options = "hover"`, `kableExtra` is using a css class `table-hover`, which is creating such a hovering effect.

Knowing this, one possible approach to attain the hovering effect for huxtables is just attaching the `table-hover` class to all huxtables which could be done easily using javascript.

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r lib}
library(magrittr)
```


```{r huxtable}
iris %>%
  head() %>%
huxtable::hux() %>%
  huxtable::set_caption("a caption")
```


```{r huxtable2}
mtcars %>%
  head() %>%
huxtable::hux() %>%
  huxtable::set_caption("another caption")
```


```{=html}
<style>

.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
}

</style>



<script>

function make_table_hover() {
  let huxtable = document.querySelectorAll('table.huxtable');
  huxtable.forEach(tab => {
    if (!tab.classList.contains('table-hover')) {
      tab.classList.add('table-hover');
    }
  });
};

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  make_table_hover();
});
</script>

```
````

Comment: Incase anyone is wondering how to wrap the javascript part up in a file and reference it in the yaml header maybe having a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543778/call-javascripts-into-rmarkdown-yaml) may be helpful.