# Is it possible to fix the head for a long html huxtable?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, kable, huxtable

This works for tables produced with `kableExtra` which is useful when inspecting long tables. I was wondering if anyone has an idea how this may be doable with `huxtable`.

Here's an example Rmd to get an idea of what I mean. I'd like the huxtable header to be fixed at the top of the page when scrolling down just like in the kable.

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r lib}
library(magrittr)
```

```{r kable}
iris %>%
  head(20) %>%
  kableExtra::kbl(caption = "a caption") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(fixed_thead = TRUE)
```

```{r huxtable}
iris %>%
  head(33) %>%
  huxtable::hux() %>%
  huxtable::set_caption("a caption")
```
````

Related to: [Is it possible to make a huxtable output hoverable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75813617/is-it-possible-to-make-a-huxtable-output-hoverable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set `position: sticky` for each `th` element of huxtable tables.

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r lib}
library(magrittr)
```

```{r huxtable}
iris %>%
  head(33) %>%
  huxtable::hux() %>%
  huxtable::set_caption("a caption")
```


```{=html}
<style>

table.huxtable th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
}

</style>

```
````

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are two lines in the `huxtable` header the accepted answer needs to be adapted as so:

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r lib}
library(magrittr)
```

```{r data-prep}
df <- data.frame(COL1_HEAD1 = letters, COL2_HEAD1 = LETTERS)
df <- rbind(df, df)
df[1, ] <- c("HEAD2", "HEAD2")
```

Works for two lined headers:
```{r huxtable-double-line-header}
df %>%
  head(33) %>%
  huxtable::hux() %>%
  huxtable::set_caption("a caption") %>%
  huxtable::set_header_rows(row = c(1, 2), value = TRUE)
```

Works for single lined headers:
```{r huxtable-single-line-header}
df %>%
  head(33) %>%
  huxtable::hux() %>%
  huxtable::set_caption("a caption")
```

```{=html}
<style>

table.huxtable th {
  position: sticky;
  background: white; /* background color prevents content below from showing through */
}

table.huxtable tr:first-child th {
    top: 0;
}

table.huxtable tr:nth-child(2) th {
    top: 30px; /* may need manual adjustment depending on actual height of first row */
}

</style>
```
````